# why wechat（微信） can do this? APNS push can Wake up parent App in background?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wechat

Why WeChat can use PUSH Notification to activate the application in background ？Even activate active the application which closed by user?

I know WeChat use Notification Service，but it can not active parent App in background！

**So，WeChat can unlimited use Silent Push?**

I try to use Silent Push+Alert+Notification Service, I can active app in background.

**I did it In Debug Mode!(Maybe Debug Mode is Different）**

But According to Apple regulations， Silent Push can not be used frequently！

---

Here is My Payload

```json
payload = {
        "aps": {
            "mutable-content": 1,
            "alert": {
                "title": "Nice To Meet U",
                "body": "推送服务测试"
            },
            "sound": "call_ring.m4a",
            "content-available": "1"
        }
    }
```

Comment: They probably have the legacy VoIP entitlement https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117939?page=3

Comment: @Paulw11 But If WeChat Continue to Use VoIP(PushKit), iOS System won't Terminate the App when it doesn't “ReportInComingCall”（Callkit）？

Comment: Not if they have the legacy entitlement.  Also, WeChat is in China, where CallKit is not permitted, which is another reason that Apple will allow them to continue to use the legacy entitlement.